# Functional programming in Python and C++

Tags: c++, python, functional-programming

Is there any good book for functional programming in Python or C++ ? I need to master functional programming in those languages.

Comment: You do realize that neither C++ nor Python are truly functional programming languages.

Comment: Functional programming is a concept. Once you grasp it, understanding language specific fp aspects will be much easier. If you want to focus on something that's functional by design, try Haskell or the more modern F#.

Comment: I agree with @darioo although I think for learning FP, using a purely functional language is very important. Not an FP/OOP mix like F# (or Scala or OCaml, for that matter) - so you have no way to stick with the parts you know and don't learning anything. Both thumbs up for Haskell.

Comment: @delnan comon don't be that guy. How many people use OO in OCaml or F# (other then for interop). Those are ok to learn. I would recomend scheme to get started because its much easier to pick up then haskell.

Comment: @nickik: I'm not using either much, but as far as I know, the OO part of (at least) OCaml *is* used (would be a shame if nobody used it). But that's the guys who already know the language and FP. A newbie trying to learn FP shouldn't spend his first weeks or months considering FP vs. OOP approach for everything he does.

Answer (score 6):

By functional programming, I assume you mean referential transparency (basically, no global state or side-effects), plus things like functions as first-class objects, polymorphic types, partial function application etc.

There is no book that I know of that covers functional programming in C++.  You could program without global state and side-effects in C++, and you can pass functions as arguments using function-typed pointers, but you couldn't get partial function application, nor anonymous lambda expressions.

Comment: Props for not making the popular mistake "FP == anonymous functions". I'd add algebraic data types and pattern matching too - although not strictly a functional concept, it's mainly used there.

Comment: Have you seen boost.bind, boost.lambda, and C++0x?

Comment: Actually, C++ supported partial function applications for a long time (at least for binary functions) through the standard std::bind1st function. In C++0x, the more general std::bind will work with any function. With the addition of proper closures and Lambdas in C++0x, it will become a truly functional language. But C++ as most people know it (C++98 standard) does not support lambda, and std::bind1st is annoying to use. EDIT: Ninja'd by Fred Nurk. :-(

Comment: @Fred @Dragontamer: But honestly, no beginner will be able to learn FP using these.

Comment: @delnan: Debatable, but I was responding to "you can't get these" above.

Comment: Just having fearures in the language and actulay using them right is not the same.

Comment: #delnan algebraic data types and pettern matching are not not what FP is about. Its more a ML (and those kind of langauges) thing.

Comment: The greatest weakness of C++ will be the `lazy` computation. Haskell makes heavy use of laziness for infinite lists for example. On the other hand, Python offers the `itertools` module which supports lazy computations and would probably be more suited.

Comment: @nickik: I know (and wrote that myself). I still consider it related as a good portion of representative FP languages include it.

Comment: @Matthieu M. is lazy computation really a functional thing? I don't see any reason why "itertools" couldn't be built in C++, C# or even Java. And Haskell is the only language that "lazy", you're not going to get that feel with Scheme's inferior delay / force statements for example.

Comment: @Dragontamer5788: laziness allow to enforce the "computed if needed" mantra which separates an imperative programming style (where you state how the program should work) and a functional programming style (where you state what the program should do, and leave it up to the compiler / runtime). I would agree it's perhaps not a "core" thing, but it's intimately linked to functional programming for me... perhaps because I only have had a light exposure to Haskell :) ?

Answer (score 6):

[Text Processing in Python](http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/) uses a functional style, and is what turned me on to functional programming. It's also a great Python/programming book in general, and I highly recommend it.

Comment: Wahoo. Thanks for this answer. I have this book, and never gave it a close enough look.

Answer (score 3):

MMhh if you want to learn functional programming you should learn a functional language first to really understand the principals then you can tree to apply them as good as you can, witch will be harder.

In python you can use functions to modify dictionarys witch is pretty functional. Make use of lambda with higher order function. You have to avoid classes and inheritance.

I cant really say much about C++. Maybe you can find some functional datastructures and then write functions on those. Look for a library that provides functions like map, reduce ...

C++0x should support closures and currying (more or less) so thing will get better.

In general:

- Try to write immutible layers on librarys (be awair that that wont performe to well)
- Look for librarys that are written in a functional way

Edit: I would recomend learning scheme its really small and you can pick it up fast. Read something like SICP or the Little Schemer that teach you recursiv thinking.

Comment: Why avoid classes and inheritance? "Class" in Python just means "type", as in `[].__class__ is list`.

Comment: @Fred Nurk You can use the classes that are given but if you model you programmes in classes and inheritance changes you will never do proper FP. Try work with dictionarys and functions instead of classes and methods.

Comment: The Little Schemer is good. Its very theory heavy but it allows you explore many ideas that you'd otherwise not know about.

Comment: C++0x does not support function currying, there is library support for partial application.

Answer (score 1):

Only a future version of C++ supports lambdas / anonymous functions. I guess Boost.Lambda supports C++ Functional programming, but it isn't really a first-class citizen of C++ yet.

Books about functional programming typically use functional languages. Like Haskell, Miranda, Lisp, Scheme, OCaml, Javascript and so forth.

EDIT: I'll withhold my opinion on Python for now. It appears I'm mistaken about a few things.

Comment: @Dragontamer5788 Thanks for reply. Can you suggest me which language to learn  Haskell, Miranda, Lisp, Scheme, OCaml ?

Comment: @Jelena: Is the goal to learn how to apply FP to C++ and Python (which is how I read your question, especially "in those languages") or to learn FP (which is how I read your comment here)?

Comment: I stand corrected on the Python issue. Must have confused it with another language. I should have checked before I posted. But @nikow, what other misconceptions are there? @Jelena Jumping in to one of the more "pure" languages like Haskell or OCaml will be harder but will force you to think more functionally. Scheme and Lisp are a bit easier to get into IMO, but they don't cover types and pattern matching.

Comment: @nikow, with proper closures (lambdas are syntactic sugar, but useful as hell), you can do everything available to you under Lambda calculus, which IMO is the core of functional programming. Sure, There is a lot of good stuff in OCaml like pattern matching, or Haskell's lazy evaluation, or Scheme's Call/cc and Hygenic Macros... but I don't consider any of that to be "Functional Programming" at its core. They're useful as hell, but not Functional Programming. They just so happen to be popular in the Functional Programming community.

Comment: @Dragontamer: I agree with the majority of that comment, but think you misunderstand Python: how are Python's closures not proper?  Are you misunderstanding that any lambda can be rewritten as a local function if the arbitrary syntax restrictions get in the way?

Comment: Just to add that, to my mind, there's a difference between a language supporting something like anonymous lambda functions and a library for that language supporting them.  Kudos to the guy who mentioned lazy evaluation, btw - left that off the list but it's really important - as in the difference between C++ and Haskell for evaluating code such as "somefunc(E)" where E is something like "10/0" (division by zero).  If somefunc returns the constant 1, then in Haskell, everything is okay, but in C++. it's not.

Comment: @Fred Nurk, the Python comment was a mistake and has been edited out of my post.

Comment: @Dragontamer: My last comment was referring to "with proper closures (lambdas are syntactic sugar, but useful as hell)", which implied, in the context here as I interpreted it, that Python doesn't have proper closures or only has "improper" closures.  Perhaps I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

In looking for info on functional programming in Python, I've found this web page to be very useful:

http://www.amk.ca/python/writing/functional

The references part contains a lot of crude information.

If you are looking for a book covering only functional programming in Python, I don't know about it.

C++ is more difficult. It has many of the ingredients (and it is steadily gaining more) for functional programming, but lacks many others. Actually, C++ was never designed for supporting functional programming, so it is typical that you'll be able to work with functional programming in some containers, but need to revert to imperative programming frequently.

Answer (score 0):

While not a book, here is a site that can at least get you started on some things.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-prog.html

As far as really understanding functional programming I would suggest something like "The Little Schemer" to get a quick handle on scheme.  You can then apply the ideas to python.

Answer (score -1):

For Perl, I can recommend "[Higher Order Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607013)".

Don't know about Python or C++ though.